# How do I center my header with my tables in my html table

Tags: html, css, web, alignment, centering

I am building a website for teachers to keep track of their students homework. The only problem is that I don't know how to align the header table with the info tables. (Each row is a table) How can I center the tables. I have been trying to figure this out for a while but I don't know how to do it. Some help would be great! (NOTE: I am just learning html and css so my code may be very messy and unresponsive.)

Thanks.

```css
    
            body{
                font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
                height: 125vh;
                background: linear-gradient(rgb(110, 2, 255) 25%, rgb(248, 250, 251) 25%, 
                rgb(248, 250, 251) 25%, rgb(248, 250, 251) 25%);
                margin: 0;
                
            }
    
            .headerText{
              font-size: 200%;
              color: white;
              text-align: center;
              font-weight: 300;
              margin-top: 130px;
              margin-bottom: 0px;
              margin-left: 185px;
              text-align: left;
            }
    
            .HaveAGoodDay{
              margin-top: 0em;
              text-align: left;
              font-size: 65%;
            }
    
            table,tr,td,th{
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 1150px;
              padding-bottom: 10px;
              padding-top: 10px;
              background-color: white;
              text-align: center;
              border-radius: 12px;
            }
    
            .table{
              filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1rem rgb(244, 244, 244));
              border: 0px white;
              border-radius: 1px; 
              overflow: hidden;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              margin-top: 1.2em;
              margin-bottom: 1.2em;
              text-align: center;
              height: 72px;
            }
    
            td{
              width: 100px;
            }
    
            .title{
              justify-content: center;
              display: flex;
              background-color: rgb(248, 250, 251)xx
            }
    
            .button{
              font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
              color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
              border: 0px white;
              border-radius: 25px;
              padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
              position: justify;
              transition: 200ms linear;
              display: inline-flex;
              height: 36px;
              }
    
              .LinkIcon{
                display: inline-flex;
                margin-right: 7.5px;
                font-size: 140%;
                text-align: right;
              }
    
            .button:hover{
              background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
            }
    
            .MinimalHomework{
              background-color: rgb(198, 238, 221);
              color: rgb(130, 194, 167);
              font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
              border: 0px white;
              border-radius: 25px;
              padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
              position: justify;
              transition: 0.1s linear;
              width: 174px;
            }
    
            .AverageHomework{
              background-color: #FFEDCF;
              color: #F3BA46;
              font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
              border: 0px white;
              border-radius: 25px;
              padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
              position: justify;
              transition: 0.1s linear;
              width: 174px;
            }
    
            .SubstantialHomework{
              background-color: #FFDBD4;
              color: #EE967F;
              font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
              border: 0px white;
              border-radius: 25px;
              padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
              position: justify;
              transition: 0.1s linear;
              width: 174px;
            }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Homework Tracker</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <div class = "headerText">
    
        <p style = "margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 0px;" id = "TimeGreeting" >Hold On</p>
        <p class = "HaveAGoodDay" >Have A Nice Day!</p>
    
        </div>
        
        <div class = "title">
    
          <table style = "margin-top: 100px;">
            <tr>
              <td style = "width: 213px;">Link</td>
              <td>Subject</td>
              <td>Homework</td>
              <td>Due</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Amount</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    
        <div class = "table">
    
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><button class = button><ion-icon name="link-outline" class="LinkIcon"></ion-icon>Homework Link</button></td>
              <td>Social Studies<br><b>Falkenstien</b></td>
              <td>Pages 4 & 5</td>
              <td>11/24/12</td>
              <td></td>
              <td><button class = MinimalHomework>Minimal Homework</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    
    
        <div class = "table">
    
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><button class = button><ion-icon name="link-outline" class="LinkIcon"></ion-icon>Homework Link</button></td>
              <td>Geography<br><b>Iris</b></td>
              <td>Slideshow</td>
              <td>12/13/21</td>
              <td></td>
              <td><button class = SubstantialHomework>Substantial Homework</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    
        </div>
    
        <div class = "table">
    
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><button class = button><ion-icon name="link-outline" class="LinkIcon"></ion-icon>Homework Link</button></td>
              <td>Math<br><b>Dekel</b></td>
              <td>Questions 1 - 10000</td>
              <td>Tomorrow</td>
              <td></td>
              <td><button class = AverageHomework>Average Homework</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    
        </div> 
    
        <div class = "table">
    
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><button class = button><ion-icon name="link-outline" class="LinkIcon"></ion-icon>Homework Link</button></td>
              <td>Gym<br><b>Rosenwald</b></td>
              <td>Nothing</td>
              <td>5/24/72</td>
              <td></td>
              <td><button class = MinimalHomework>Minimal Homework</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    
        </div>
    
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: How do you mean align? Like make them all have the same width?

Comment: Make the header mach up with the text. Right now, the each header is slightly to the right of the column is is representing.